# Trivial examples for the Chern number from the potential for quantized transport

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, quantum-transport

I'm trying to understand the phenomena of quantized electron transport better. The difficult step is that for any Hamiltonian (where $V(x,t)$ is periodic in both arguments and is a slow function of $t$ so that adiabaticity is valid) ,

\begin{equation}
 H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x,t),
\end{equation}

the Chern number which governs the magnitude of the quantized current is a very non-trivial function of the band structure. For now I have given up trying to understand the origin and topological meaning of the Chern number better (for which several questions have already been asked).

My question is: Are there any special forms of the potential energy function $V(x,t)$ for which the Chern number is analytically known and is there any argument (mathematical or otherwise) to understand why such a special form has such-and-such a Chern number.

Particularly I wonder if a function of the form $V(x,t) = V(x/a + t/T)$ is simple to understand?